# Probability calculation given partial information

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two opaque boxes, A and B, as well as five colored balls: four red and one blue. We are interested in the location of the blue ball, which someone has hidden in one of the two boxes. We didn't get to see the balls being placed, of course, but we know the algorithm that was used to randomly place balls:

- Flip a coin to decide which box to put the blue ball into
- Then, fill the boxes with red balls such that there is exactly one ball in box A, and the other four are in box B

After the balls have been placed, we begin drawing from box B, one at a time, and find three red balls. At this point there remains one ball left in box B, and box A still has the one ball it started with. The question is, how likely is the blue ball to be in each box respectively?

I think it is four times as likely to be in box A, with various justifications, such as:

1. Which is more likely, that it was in B but would be the fourth one we draw, or that it was never in B to begin with? The latter was a priori 50%, and the former only 12.5%.
2. There were at the start five "locations" it could be: A, B1, B2, B3, B4; we have eliminated three of these, leaving only A and B4, but B4 was originally less likely than A (I think this is actually the same argument as (1) above, but I'm not sure).
3. I've run some simulations which suggest the 80% split but I'm not certain I did them right, and I might instead have just encoded my expected outcome into the simulation.

But of course there is the "obvious" argument that it is now a coin-flip because there are only two locations left; this strikes me as the same fallacy as the Monty Hall problem, but with no omniscient narrator to reveal doors to me I'm not sure the same arguments apply. And perhaps in argument (2) B4 *was* less likely originally, but having gathered the information about B1-B3 B4 has become more likely?

I would like to prove this out using conditional probabilities, which seems like it ought to be manageable, but it has been a long time since I wrote any of that and it isn't clear exactly what my givens and conditions are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct when you say "I think it is four times as likely to be in box A".  There are two cases:

- Blue ball in box A.  Prior probability $\frac12$.  Likelihood of three reds drawn from box B proportional to $1$. Posterior probability proportional to $\frac12 \times 1 $.
- Blue ball in box B.  Prior probability $\frac12$.  Likelihood of three reds drawn from box B proportional to $\frac14$. Posterior probability proportional to $\frac12 \times \frac14$.

So given that three red balls were drawn from box B, the posterior probability that the blue ball is in box A is $\dfrac{\frac12 \times 1 }{\frac12 \times 1 + \frac12 \times \frac14} = \dfrac{4}{5}$, which corresponds to your simulation.